# Properties of covariance matrix of two random vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, covariance

I know that the covariance matrix of a random vector must be symmetric and positive semidefinite. What about a covariance matrix between two random vectors? Does it have the same properties?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn’t. For instance, from the facts that you cite it follows that the [cross-covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-covariance_matrix) of $X$ and $-X$ does not have these properties (where $X$ is a random vector that is not almost surely zero).